# Java Android: Save full-size Phorto and view Scaled Image - dont appear

Tags: android, imageview, scale, photo

I would like to create an app that will capture a full size photo and then show it as a miniature in the activity. But when I run app and take photo, it will be saved to gallery but in activity miniature doesn't appear.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp2.MESSAGE";

private ImageView mImageView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();    
}

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {     
      handleBigCameraPhoto(); 
  }
}

 private void handleBigCameraPhoto() 
{
    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) 
    {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }
}

private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    int scaleFactor = 1000;
    if (targetH > 0)  {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }
    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}


protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle State) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(State);
    State.putString("filepath", mCurrentPhotoPath);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = state.getString("filepath");
    setPic();  
}
```

The `ImageView` in the activity layout is defined like this:

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"  
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You randomly added "file:" for no reason at all.

`mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: I added it after mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); but still nothing changed.. Area of ImageView is still empty.

Comment: whoa, does your app crash?

Comment: While using just: mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath(); miniature work :) Thnak You! There is another issue- when I change the rotation of the display- miniature will disappear. Can you please advise how to deal with it?

Comment: you can save the filepath and reload the image when the activity is restored http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/

Comment: I adeed this methods:
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle State) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state), 
But I got error: divide by zero. With another experiments i found that dimensions of mImageView (targetW and targetH) are after resume = 0. Can you please tell me why it happend or how to deal with this problem?